# How i can change svg icon color?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I need change color of that icon :
[image]

I try `fill` but it not works.

Styles of that icon

```
import styled from 'styled-components'


export default styled.img`
height: 14px;
padding-right: 7px;
fill: #d85040;
`
```

And in component :

```
import google from '../img/google-brands.svg'

<SocialCont>
                    <SocialLink>
                    <CompanyLogo src={google} alt="facebook"/>
                    <SocialText>Google</SocialText>     
                    </SocialLink>
                </SocialCont>
```

I use React and Styled Components.

Comment: So, it's an `img` with an `svg` `src`? Do you have a link to the working code?

Comment: You can change icon color with fill in .svg file

Comment: fyi: there is a typo in "or sign in with"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG images are actually just glorified HTML elements.

You can edit your SVG images to set the `fill` and `stroke` attributes to anything you want.

You can also give SVG elements `id` and `class` attributes and use styled-components to change those.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an svg passed as a source to an image, i.e. `<img src="image.svg" />` , it may not be impossible to implement it. It is, however possible if you are injecting the `svg` code directly into the page.

In this case, simply change the `fill` attribute on the tags that you want to change the color on.

Since you asked this on the `react` channel, I'm assuming you're using React. You could simply create a component that returns the SVG so that your code may be cleaner.